# Remove child node except first using javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to remove all `li` except first child
This code is removing all `li`..

```
function clearAll() {
    var sidemenu = document.getElementById('side_menu');
    while (sidemenu.childNodes.length > 1) {
            sidemenu.removeChild(sidemenu.lastChild);
    }
}
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: What does the corresponding HTML look like?

Comment: @AnthonyGrist it was removing all li tag

Comment: I know, you already said that in your question which I read. That's not really a response to my comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing:

```
while (sidemenu.childNodes.length > 2) {
  //...
}
```

(Change the condition in the while loop.)

`sidemenu.childNodes` actually has one extra text field. For that reason we need to increment the number in the condition of while loop.

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/0Lxh8fvz/5/) (checkout the console)

That ways, all of your `<li>`'s except the first one will be removed.

Comment: Why is that correct while what they currently have isn't?

Comment: @BDhara I believe I was the first one to answer this. Please upvote and accept this answer if you found it good enough.

Comment: @RahulDesai sure will do it

Comment: @Pete What I'm looking for is an explanation of **why** changing the condition from 1 to 2 fixes the problem. Because, while I'm no doubt missing something, it seems to me that if you take away *one* child element while there's *more than one* child element, the condition `length > 1` should be correct to remove all but the first child element. Why isn't that the case? If he explains that, I'm more than happy to change my downvote to an upvote.

Comment: @Pete I thought I'd done that in my first comment - "Why is that correct while what they currently have isn't?". Perhaps that wasn't as clear as I'd thought. If it's "quite plainly obvious" I would genuinely love somebody to explain it to me, because right now this just seems like a guess that increasing the number in the comparison will work without knowing why that would be the case.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist Checkout [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0Lxh8fvz/5/) that I extended from Rick's. If you look closely, `sidemenu.childNodes` actually has one extra `text` field. For that reason we need to increment the number in the condition of `while` loop. Answer updated.

Answer (score 6):

use `sidemenu.children` instead of `sidemenu.childNodes`

`sidemenu.children` will return only the elements which are under the given node.

`sidemenu.childNodes` will return both elements as well as text nodes, which is not the list of items you require.  If you check the value returned by `lastChild` it would be an empty text node and not an `li`.  That is why all the `li` were getting removed.

```
function clearAll() {
    var sidemenu = document.getElementById('side_menu');
    while (sidemenu.children.length > 1) {
        sidemenu.removeChild(sidemenu.lastChild);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the best answer, because it will work with any layout.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Element.replaceChildren()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/replaceChildren).

```js
sidemenu.replaceChildren(sidemenu.firstElementChild);
```

Answer (score 0):

To keep the first child change

```
sidemenu.childNodes.length > 1
```

to

```
sidemenu.childNodes.length > 2

function clearAll() {
    var sidemenu = document.getElementById('side_menu');
    while (sidemenu.childNodes.length > 2) {
            sidemenu.removeChild(sidemenu.lastChild);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you use jQuery you could do this:

```
$('#side_menu li:not(:first)').remove();
```

Comment: this post doesn't have jQuery tagged on it, don't just introduce a library unless the question offers you the option to

Comment: Ok, but if he does not know how to use jQuery somebody can show him. In my opinion the code is more transparent if you use jQuery... I will delete this post if he does not want to use jQuery...

Comment: yes but you are adding a whole extra library and asking OP to learn it for one problem

Comment: yes but if he's trying to make more complex application he will sooner or later need it :)

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45176/when-is-use-jquery-not-a-valid-answer-to-a-javascript-question

Comment: I didn't say to him that he must use jQuery (like "You should use jQuery...") but if he is maybe already using it he could solve his problem on more elegant way. I do not know since when offering new ideas is not desirable.